# If / Else Statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem placing the IF / ELSE statement without breaking the rest of the page.

I have a following banner on my page :

```
    <div class="awesome-banner">

                    <div class="image-wrap<?php echo $banner ? '' : ' awesome-hide'; ?>">
                        <?php $banner_url = $banner ? wp_get_attachment_url($banner) : ''; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" class="awesome-file-field" value="<?php echo $banner; ?>" name="awesome_banner">
                        <img class="awesome-banner-img" src="<?php echo esc_url($banner_url); ?>">
                        <a class="close awesome-remove-banner-image">&times;</a>
                    </div>



                    <div class="button-area<?php echo $banner ? ' awesome-hide' : ''; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                        <a href="#" class="awesome-banner-drag awesome-btn awesome-btn-info"><?php _e('Upload banner', 'awesome'); ?></a>
                        <p class="help-block"><?php _e('(Upload a banner for your profile. Banner size is (825x300) pixel. )', 'awesome'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- .awesome-banner -->

<?php do_action('awesome_settings_after_banner', $current_user, $profile_info); ?>
```

I need to place in the following statement inside this banner ( PLEASE CORRECT IF WRONG ):

```
<?
if ((current_user_can('manager')) )
{ ?>    
    <div class="access-restricted">
      <h5>Sign In Or Sign Up</h5>
       <p class="non-manager-notice">You need to be a manager to upload a banner</p>
       <div class="upgrade-button">
         <a href="#" class="button-green-upgrade">Upgrade Account</a>
       </div>
    </div>  
<?  
    return;
    } else{ 
    return false;
}                   
?>
```

So basically it should state the following inside this banner :

If the current user is user role `"manager"` then instead of the `<div class="button-area">` it should display `<div class="access-restricted">`

Otherwise just go on as normally.

I am trying to place the statement directly inside like this :

```
    <div class="awesome-banner">

                        <div class="image-wrap<?php echo $banner ? '' : ' awesome-hide'; ?>">
                            <?php $banner_url = $banner ? wp_get_attachment_url($banner) : ''; ?>
                            <input type="hidden" class="awesome-file-field" value="<?php echo $banner; ?>" name="awesome_banner">
                            <img class="awesome-banner-img" src="<?php echo esc_url($banner_url); ?>">
                            <a class="close awesome-remove-banner-image">&times;</a>
                        </div>

                        // Here I am placing my statement like this
                        <?
        if ((current_user_can('manager')) )
        { ?>    
            <div class="access-restricted">
              <h5>Sign In Or Sign Up</h5>
               <p class="non-manager-notice">You need to be a manager to upload a banner</p>
               <div class="upgrade-button">
                 <a href="#" class="button-green-upgrade">Upgrade Account</a>
               </div>
            </div>  
        <?  
            return;
            } else{ 
            return false;
        }                   
        ?>
    // End of my statement

                        <div class="button-area<?php echo $banner ? ' awesome-hide' : ''; ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                            <a href="#" class="awesome-banner-drag awesome-btn awesome-btn-info"><?php _e('Upload banner', 'awesome'); ?></a>
                            <p class="help-block"><?php _e('(Upload a banner for your profile. Banner size is (825x300) pixel. )', 'awesome'); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- .awesome-banner -->

<?php do_action('awesome_settings_after_banner', $current_user, $profile_info); ?>
```

It displays the content correctly for the role, but it breaks the rest of the content on the page behind the awesome banner div.

Am I closing my statement and everything else correctly ?? Thanks

Comment: Are you meaning to `return`? That will stop code after that point...

Comment: If you're not within a function, you shouldn't be returning anything. Try taking out the return statements.

Comment: @Rasclatt, @maiorano84 -  Ok, `return;` and `return false;` taken off, but now it is displaying both `divs`

Rest of the page behind the awesome-banner div is showing ok though

Comment: Then you need the one `<div>` block between the `if() {}` and the other between the `else {}`. Is that what you are wanting? It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Rasclatt, yeah I think that's exactly what I need, would you be able to put it into the code, so I can see it visually ? I'm no too god with php, so not sure where how exactly to place these. Thanks

Comment: Which are the two div blocks that should be `if/else`?  `IF-><div class="access-restricted"> ELSE-><div class="button-area`...etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Further to my (and @maiorano84's comments), the `return` will stop your code if either condition is met (true or false):

```
if(current_user_can('manager')) { ?>    
    <div class="access-restricted">
        <h5>Sign In Or Sign Up</h5>
        <p class="non-manager-notice">You need to be a manager to upload a banner</p>
        <div class="upgrade-button">
            <a href="#" class="button-green-upgrade">Upgrade Account</a>
        </div>
    </div><?
        // If you need to record a true or false here, assign to a variable.
        // Don't return or your code will stop here.
        $manager = true;
    }
else { ?>
    <div class="button-area<?php if($banner) echo ' awesome-hide'; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <a href="#" class="awesome-banner-drag awesome-btn awesome-btn-info"><?php _e('Upload banner', 'awesome'); ?></a>
        <p class="help-block"><?php _e('(Upload a banner for your profile. Banner size is (825x300) pixel. )', 'awesome'); ?></p>
    </div><?php 
        // If you need true/false, assign here
        $manager = false;
    } ?>
```

Comment: Ok, im trying the following, no need for the `return` . But still both divs are showing ..

`<?
if(current_user_can('manager')) { ?>    
    <div class="access-restricted">
        <h5>Sign In Or Sign Up</h5>
        <p class="non-manager-notice">You need to be a manager to upload a banner</p>
          <a href="#" class="button-green-upgrade">Upgrade Account</a>
    </div><?
    } else 
    ?>

//Start of the second div`

Comment: What do you want between the else? I don't know what you want there. What is your second div start with?

Comment: Is it `<div class="button-area`  that is the else?

Comment: No problem. Make sure to check the answer correct so no one comes to try and answer your question.